# How to get value displayed inside drop down not the value of it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i want to get value inside the drop down using javascript (not the value)
for example

```
<select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
<option value="1">Audi</option>
<option value="2">BMW</option>
<option value="3">Mercedes</option>
<option value="4">Volvo</option>
</select>
```

when i select audi i want to get value Audi not the value "1"

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You selected: " + x;
}
</script>
```

Comment: You can select the option tag whose value is 1 and get its innertext

Comment: function myFunction(){ alert($('#mySelect option:selected').text()) }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With jQuery, you can do it something like this. Listen to the `change` event of the dropdown, and get the inner text of the option which is selected.

```js
$("#mySelect").change(function() {
  console.log($(this).find("option:selected").text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="1">Audi</option>
  <option value="2">BMW</option>
  <option value="3">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="4">Volvo</option>
</select>
```

Comment: All codes are right but this code feels like a neat and simple code .thats why I choose this as the right answer. thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use `value` & `selectedIndex` & `textContent` to get the value and the option text

```js
function myFunction(elem) {
  let k = elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].textContent;
  console.log(elem.value,k)
}
```

```html
<select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction(this)">
  <option value="1">Audi</option>
  <option value="2">BMW</option>
  <option value="3">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="4">Volvo</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to take the text from the selected option:

Using vanilla JavaScript:

```js
function myFunction(el){
  var text = el.options [el.selectedIndex].textContent
  document.getElementById("demo").textContent = "You selected: " +text;
}
myFunction(document.getElementById("mySelect")); //Call the function on page load for default selected option
```

```html
<select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction(this)">
  <option value="1">Audi</option>
  <option value="2">BMW</option>
  <option value="3">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="4">Volvo</option>
</select>

<div id="demo"></div>
```

Using jQuery:

```js
$("#mySelect").change(function(){
  var text = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
  $("#demo").text("You selected: " +text);
});

$("#mySelect").trigger("change"); //Trigger the event on page load for default selected option.
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="1">Audi</option>
  <option value="2">BMW</option>
  <option value="3">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="4">Volvo</option>
</select>

<div id="demo"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the text, not the value try below code-

```js
function myFunction(elem) {
  console.log(elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].text);
}
```

```html
<select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction(this)">
<option value="1">Audi</option>
<option value="2">BMW</option>
<option value="3">Mercedes</option>
<option value="4">Volvo</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`document.querySelector('#mySelect').addEventListener('input', function() {
    console.log(this.options[this.selectedIndex].innerHTML);
});`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

function myFunction(){

var selectedData = $(this).find('option:selected').html();

}